# Updating a UWP app, in Kiosk Mode, delivered by the Windows Store

Tags: uwp, windows-store, windows-dev-center

I would like to write a UWP app that is hosted in the Windows Store for Business, so allowing me to push out updates to all our PCs running the app.

I would also like the app run as a Kiosk app, I think it's referred to as "Assigned access method".

Can someone tell me what happens when I push an update to the app to the Windows Store? Is the app automatically updated and forced upon the user of the Kiosk app, or does the user get the option to reject the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone tell me what happens when I push an update to the app to
>   the Windows Store? Is the app automatically updated and forced upon
>   the user of the Kiosk app, or does the user get the option to reject
>   the update?

When your update passes certification, users cannot update your app through Assigned access method and they need to log out of the kiosk-mode. The update can be downloaded in background and get finished when they close and re-launch your app.

There's no option to reject the update directly. But if users turn off `Update apps automatically`in Store app setting, they could decide to update your app manually or not:
[image]
For **[mandatory update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates#mandatory-dashboard)**, you could enable it by checking `Make this update mandatory` when create your submission. But this feature requires developers to use the mandatory setting to enforce mandatory app updates in their own code. For example, you could disable some functionality until the mandatory update is installed.

Comment: I still don't quite get it. When the automatic app updates are left on, will the kiosk be updated and restarted when an update comes along? Can the app have a say when the restart happens?

Comment: @Zhendong Wu - MSFT, is this still the case today? Also how does this affect Side-loaded UWP apps? Our app does not seem to update, despite having the "Check everytime the application runs" option selected. This doesn't seem to be a scalable model for updating our app.